# Application.ProductVersion, what's the command application equivalent?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to add an 'update' function to a tool I'm creating, I followed a tutorial on making an update button but my application is a Command Application. I changed all the messagebox's to console.writeline but one part isn't working. Help?

```
Console.WriteLine("Now Checking for updates.\nPlease be patient as we check for updates.");
                    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://WEBSITE.com/TEXT/FILE");
                    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                    System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                    string newestversion = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    string currentversion = ***Application***.ProductVersion;
                    Version vOnline = new Version(newestversion);
                    Version vLocal = new Version(currentversion);
                    if (vOnline > vLocal)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Update Found!\nNewest Version: " + newestversion + ".");
                    }
                    else if (vLocal == vOnline)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("No Updates Found.\nYou are on the newest version.");
                    }
                    else if (vLocal > vOnline)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("No Updates Found.\nYou are on a pre-release version of the program.");
                    }
```

What do I put instead of Application to make it work? I'm new to C#, so any help appreciated!

Comment: Not the exact function but `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version` might do